# How to check if empty and display rich text field (HTML) in Hippo CMS template

Tags: java, jsp, hippocms

I have a project built using the Hippo CMS Java framework. I have created a new document type which contains a rich text field. In the document type bean I have a property of type `HippoHtml`:

```
@HippoEssentialsGenerated(internalName = "acm:abstract")
public HippoHtml getAbstract() {
    return getHippoHtml("acm:abstract");
}
```

Other fields of `String` type work fine:

```
@HippoEssentialsGenerated(internalName = "acm:title")
public String getTitle() {
    return getProperty("acm:title");
}
```

In the JSP template I can check and display simple properties like this:

```
<c:if test="${ not empty result.title  }">
  <h1>${ result.title }</h1>
</c:if>
```

However, for the `HippoHtml` property, I cannot get the template to recognize the field. I have tried the following:

```
<%--@elvariable id="result" type="org.acm.beans.CustomDocument"--%>

<c:if test="${ not empty result.abstract}">
  ${ result.abstract}
</c:if>
...
<c:if test="${ not empty result.abstract  }">
  <hst:html hippohtml="${ result.abstract }"/>
</c:if>
...
<c:if test="${ not empty result.html.abstract  }">
  <hst:html hippohtml="${ result.html.abstract }"/>
</c:if>
...
<c:if test="${ not empty result.html.content}">
  <hst:html hippohtml="${ result.html.content}"/>
</c:if>
```

I would like to investigate the `HippoHtml` type. Where in the project files (or online) can I find a class definition for `org.hippoecm.hst.content.beans.standard.HippoHtml` in order to see the object properties and methods?

How do I check if the document property `acm:abstract` has a value, then display it in my template?

Comment: For anyone looking for the Java docs, I found them here http://javadoc.onehippo.org/hippo-cms7/7.8.x/site-toolkit/org/hippoecm/hst/content/beans/standard/HippoHtml.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the code:
https://code.onehippo.org/

Or the api:
http://javadoc.onehippo.org/11.1/hippo-site-toolkit/

Or a more general overview page which includes the above links:
https://www.onehippo.org/library/about/developer-info.html

To see if it is empty you can call

```
<hst:html hippohtml="${ result.abstract}" var="foo"/>
```

And then test if foo exists.

Comment: I get the error " "${ result.abstract }" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${ result.abstract }]
" I get this same "invalid expression" error when I try this `<hst:html hippohtml="${ result.abstract.content }"...`

Comment: Not sure, but maybe it doesn't like your use of abstract since that is a java keyword. I recall there being some issues with that.

Comment: That's interesting... It did the trick! I renamed the property to htmlContent and it worked.